# html5 canvas drawing mutiple images and overlapping

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I draw mutiple images in canvas, but i want that the user be able to define the overlapping of the image. In other words, th user select the image that appears in the front, and the image that appears in behind.
how can i accomplished that?

Comment: By using `z-index` or am i missing some information?

Comment: z-index won't help for drawing images on a canvas. You should clear the canvas and redraw all the images according to the required indexes (the lowest one first).

Comment: Do you mean that you want to draw several images on a _single_ or on _multiple_ canvases?

Comment: Additionally, what do you want to accomplish: Changing the order of the images or handling the user input?

Comment: on a single canvas. i already do that. i only miss the overlapping..

Comment: this project consist in an ipad magazine editor. and the canvas represent the ipad screen. so the user will be able to define the overlapping of the images

Comment: Your best choice would be to store all the images in an array and assign a custom z-index if needed. Then sort them accordingly and draw them in a loop.

Comment: you can use inline CSS every div where you are using canvas for overcome  the overlapping issue

Answer (score 5):

Use "min-height" and "min-width" while creating the div for randering chart.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this, assuming you only care to render the next image to be on the canvas 'in front' or 'behind' the images which were already rendered (ie not to post-facto render an image 'between' two images you already rendered on the canvas) using the `globalCompositeOperation` property of the 2d canvas context. MDN has [an illustrative example](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/canvas-tutorial/6_1_canvas_composite.html) and [comprehensive documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Canvas_tutorial/Compositing). Basically, in your case if you want to render the next image 'above', you would use `"source-over"` as a value for this property, if you want to render it behind the existing content, use `"destination-over"`.

If you want more detailed control over the overlap of more than 2 images, you will have to adjust the order in which they are rendered as suggested in the comments so far (ie put the images in an array, sort the array in the desired fashion, and then render them).

Answer (score 0):

The image on top is always the last image drawn.

A solution I use when bringing an image to the front, when it's selected, is to store all the images in array - this will also be the draw order - and the image to be on top is simply taken out of the array and placed at the end, thus being on top.